# Current query taking a minute to run, when to create separate queries vs just one?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

So I am dealing with what a query with a decent amount of joins and a lot of many to main relationships.

The only tables with a one to many would be invoice, so, and xc_orders.

Each of these tables also have hundreds of thousands of rows -

- invoice has 822,967 rows
- invc_fee has 208,021 rows
- invc_tender has 821,799 rows
- customer has 377,515 rows
- cust_address has 665,633
- invc_item has 1,975,436 rows
- invn_sbs has 122,669 rows
- so has 195,169 rows
- xc_orders has 267,165 rows

If I split up the query below into two separate queries based on the WHERE conditions it changes the length of time to run the queries from 56.8 seconds to 5.36 seconds for the first query and 5.32 seconds for the second query.  I take it this is due to the OR clause? Was just running the queries on their own and looking at the time to run these without caching the results the most obvious way to determine if it's alright to combine the WHERE conditions? Was there something I was missing that would allow for me to speed up the results and still keep the OR conditional statements in there?Thanks for the help.

For what it's worth this was being run a MySQL 5.5 database.

```
 SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE i.invc_no, DATE_FORMAT(i.created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS invcdate, IF(i.so_no LIKE '%WEB%', substring(i.so_no,5,10),i.so_no) AS so, format(SUM(it.amt),2) AS invc_amt, i.invc_type, format(ii.qty,0) as qty, isb.description1, format(ii.price,2) As price, replace(isb.dcs_code,' ','') AS dcs, isb.siz, isb.attr, trim(i.note) AS invc_note, trim(so.note) AS so_note, trim(xo.notes) AS xcart_notes, trim(xo.customer_notes) AS xcart_cust_notes
            FROM      rp.invoice AS i
            LEFT JOIN rp.invc_fee AS ife ON i.invc_sid = ife.invc_sid
            LEFT JOIN rp.invc_tender AS it ON it.invc_sid = i.invc_sid
            LEFT JOIN rp.customer AS c ON i.cust_sid = c.cust_sid
            LEFT JOIN rp.cust_address AS ca ON c.cust_sid = ca.cust_sid /* NEW */
            LEFT JOIN rp.invc_item AS ii ON ii.invc_sid = i.invc_sid
            LEFT JOIN rp.invn_sbs AS isb ON isb.item_sid = ii.item_sid
            LEFT JOIN rp.so AS so ON so.so_sid = i.so_sid
            LEFT JOIN dev.xc_orders AS xo ON xo.orderid = REPLACE(so.so_no,'WEB0','')
            WHERE     i.invc_no != '0' AND (c.email_addr = 'email@gmail.com' OR (c.first_name = 'Eric' AND c.last_name = 'MXXXX' AND ca.address1 LIKE '1234%' AND ca.zip = '12345')) AND IFNULL(ife.fee_type, 0) >= 0
            GROUP BY  i.invc_no, i.created_date, i.so_no, i.invc_type, ii.qty, isb.description1, ii.price, isb.dcs_code, isb.siz, isb.attr, i.note, so.note, xo.notes, xo.customer_notes, ii.item_pos, ii.item_sid
            ORDER BY  i.created_date desc, i.invc_no, i.invc_type
```

Here is the explain results

```
 id    select     table  type    possible_keys    key_len    ref             rows    filtered    Extra 
 1     SIMPLE     i      ALL     INVC_NO                                     822967  91.92       Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
 1     SIMPLE     ife    ref     PRIMARY          8          rp.i.INVC_SID   2080    100.00      Using where; Using index
 1     SIMPLE     it     ref     PRIMARY          8          rp.i.INVC_SID   8217    100.00 
 1     SIMPLE     c      eq_ref  PRIMARY          8          rp.i.CUST_SID   1       100.00      Using where
 1     SIMPLE     ca     ref     PRIMARY          8          rp.c.CUST_SID   6656    100.00      Using where
 1     SIMPLE     ii     ref     PRIMARY          8          rp.i.INVC_SID   19754   100.00 
 1     SIMPLE     isb    ref     PRIMARY          8          rp.ii.ITEM_SID  1226    100.00      Using where
 1     SIMPLE     so     eq_ref  PRIMARY          8          rp.i.SO_SID     1       100.00      Using where
 1     SIMPLE     xo     eq_ref  PRIMARY          4          func            1       100.00      Using where
```

Comment: You can run two separate queries and use `union` or `union all` to combine them.

Comment: have you got the query explaination plan? might help identify where you could add an index or opportunities for optimization. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: How does the query execution time change if you omit the "GROUP BY" clause?

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance @Trent I've gone ahead and added that and will do some research into the explain results myself.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance, I would suggest replacing 
 LEFT JOIN rp.customer AS c ON i.cust_sid = c.cust_sid
            LEFT JOIN rp.cust_address AS ca ON c.cust_sid = ca.cust_sid /* NEW */
....
 WHERE     i.invc_no != '0' AND (c.email_addr = 'email@gmail.com' OR (c.first_name = 'Eric' AND c.last_name = 'MXXXX' AND ca.address1 LIKE '1234%' AND ca.zip = '12345')) AND IFNULL(ife.fee_type, 0) >= 0

With

LEFT JOIN
( SELECT * FROM rp.customer WHERE c.email_addr = 'email@gmail.com' OR (c.first_name = 'Eric' AND c.last_name = 'MXXXX' ) AS c ON i.cust_sid = c.cust_sid
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM rp.cust_addr WHERE ca.address1 LIKE '1234%' AND ca.zip = '12345') AS ca ON c.cust_sid = ca.cust_sid /* NEW */
.... 
WHERE     i.invc_no != '0' AND IFNULL(ife.fee_type, 0) >= 0

Comment: Unfortunately the subqueries caused the query to take longer, I was able to shorten the query length slightly by changing one of the LEFT JOINS to an INNER JOIN but that's all I've been able to do to speed up the query so far. But thank you for your input.